# Wget for specific URL for offline reading

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a specific URL, such as `http://website.com/index.html`, or `http://website.com/example.html`

This is for offline reading, where I want Wget to grab all related images, JavaScript, and CSS files.

Using `wget -k -m http://website.com/index.html` will download the entire site instead of only `http://website.com/index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `--page-requisites` (or `-p`) option; see [the man page on gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#index-page-requisites-124).